# Why Property Observer does not work for Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

when I change the selecteddrive by using a button(ontapGesture),it prints "value changed",but when I use the Picker to change the value, the didset function did not work.

```
enum WheelDrive: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case frontdrive
    case reardrive
    case Fourwheeldrive
    case Neutral
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

@State var selecteddrive = WheelDrive.Fourwheeldrive {
    willSet(newValue){ print("value changed")}
}
Picker(selection: $selecteddrive, label: Text("WheelDrive")) {
    Text("前驱").tag(WheelDrive.frontdrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("后驱").tag(WheelDrive.reardrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("四驱").tag(WheelDrive.Fourwheeldrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("滑行").tag(WheelDrive.Neutral)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom binding

```
Picker(selection: Binding(get: {selecteddrive}, set: {selecteddrive = $0}), label: Text("WheelDrive")) { //<-- Here
    Text("前驱").tag(WheelDrive.frontdrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("后驱").tag(WheelDrive.reardrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("四驱").tag(WheelDrive.Fourwheeldrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("滑行").tag(WheelDrive.Neutral)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
```

Or you can use `.onChange` for capturing value.

```
Picker(selection: $selecteddrive, label: Text("WheelDrive")) {
    Text("前驱").tag(WheelDrive.frontdrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("后驱").tag(WheelDrive.reardrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("四驱").tag(WheelDrive.Fourwheeldrive)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    Text("滑行").tag(WheelDrive.Neutral)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
.onChange(of: selecteddrive, perform: { (selecteddrive) in //<- Here
    print(selecteddrive)
})
```